# Looking for "open" paragraph mark

Tags: font-identification

I used a typeface for display purposes, but I forget which it was. It has a distinctive "open" paragraph mark, with space between the two vertical strokes.

[image]

Comment: A system font - Windows, Mac, or other? A font that came free with some other software - Corel, Office, Adobe? Do you regularly download free fonts, or buy them (where? Adobe, Linotype, House); or do you typically purchase real expensive fonts? All that will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not exact but [Carrois Gothic](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Carrois+Gothic) could probably work for you:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this looks like a pretty good match.

PT AdverGothic Cyrillic

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of results out there that are very close. Here are a few that might work:

1. [FF Mark - Book or Regular](https://www.fonts.com/font/fontfont/ff-mark)

[image]

2. [Tablet Gothic - Regular](https://www.fonts.com/font/typetogether/tablet-gothic)

[image]

3. [Verb - Regular or Medium](https://www.fonts.com/font/yellow-design-studio/verb)

[image]

4. [Amiko](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amiko) (free Google font!)

[image]